# Why do CircleCI variants not appear to work when combined? Cannot get Firefox Geckodriver to work

Tags: ruby, rspec, circleci

Using Ruby `2.4.0` and `2.4.1`, I cannot get CircleCI to recognize the Language image variants, other than `-browsers`, e.g. the stated variants of `-browsers-legacy` etc say manifest ... not found.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/#ruby

Because of this I cannot seem to get past an issue with Firefox tests not starting Firefox in CircleCI.  It works if I base my Circle config image `ruby-2.6.2-browsers` but locally I've been unable to install Ruby version `2.6.2` as my rbenv says definition not found for `2.6.2`

However when using `2.4.1` in CircleCI I get `Net::ReadTimeout` as Firefox doesn't respond (but Chrome does).

When I switch CircleCI to be based on an image of `2.6.2-browsers` both Firefox and Chrome work ok.

So currently I have to have my local Ruby be `2.4.0` (in my Gemnfile) as when I try `rbenv install 2.6.2` (for the version that works in CircleCI) it says image definition not found

Is there a way to get my local environment and CircleCI environment using the same version of Ruby ?

For now I am having to have

- local be `2.4.1` (in `.ruby-version` file)
- `.circleci/config` file having `image: circleci/ruby:2.6.2-browsers`

While trying to get this right I've also encountered

- new webdrivers gem had issues and I had to go back to older gems for now
- Firefox unable to start
- other issues
- unable to have Ruby version specified inside my Gemfile as different environments have different versions (I'm avoiding any kind of variable for now)

I'm not listing these in details here to resolve but to indicate these environments are a bit fragile right now with multiple issuers affecting what works where depending on

- OS version
- Ruby version
- image versions
- Firefox versions

Answer (score 0):

Older patch releases don't get published on Docker Hub after a certain point. If you want the latest software available in variant images such as `-browser`, you need to use a later version of Ruby 2.4 such as 2.4.6. For example, this image `circleci/ruby:2.4.6-browsers`.

If for whatever reason you can't do that, take the CircleCI Ruby 2.4.1 image, the standard version not the variant, and then build your own Docker image for that that has the software you need in it.